# Fastest/shortest way to the root folders?

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

I'm using Google Drive SDK v2 on Android to get the list of root folders. Currently I see these required steps - which seem to load forever. Is there no faster way?

I tried to use the search with the q= parameter but I don't get it to work (FileList vs. Files.List) - different API levels?

```
FileList files = drive.files().list().setQ("'root' in parents and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed=false");
```

This is what I do currently:

```
About about = drive.about().get().execute();
if (about != null) {
    ChildList childList = drive.children().list(about.getRootFolderId()).execute();
    if (childList != null) {
        List<ChildReference> listChildReference = childList.getItems();
        for (ChildReference childReference : listChildReference) {
            File file = drive.files().get(childReference.getId()).execute();
            if (file != null) {
                String fileExtension = file.getFileExtension();
                String mimeType = file.getMimeType();
                if (mimeType != null
                        && mimeType.equals("application/vnd.google-apps.folder")
                        && (fileExtension == null || fileExtension.equals(""))) {
                    Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), file.getTitle());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What's the fastest for an Android app?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

My **personal** opinion is avoid the Drive SDK and call the REST API directly. It's a fairly simple API, and the way the documentation is structured, you are forced to understand it anyway in order to use the SDK. You have the benefit that if something doesn't work, you can directly compare your app with what's happening on the wire and resolve any problems.

Comment: Sorry, this is bad advice. Use the Drive API which is part of the Drive SDK (or maybe this is what you mean?).

Comment: My comment was that I prefer to use the lower level HTTP API, form my own URL and parse the results myself. Although this is is more lines of code, (a) it's my code, so if it's broke I can easily fix it, (b) there is a direct relationship between what my code does and what happens on the wire, so again if there is a problem it is easy to diagnose and fix, (c) it's one less layer of dependency in my stack. The Java API client is tagged as beta and is being updated every two months. That's not a great recipe for production code. Just my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

```
@Override
protected ArrayList<File> doInBackground(final Void... voids) {
    ArrayList<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();

    Files.List request = null;

    boolean ok = true;

    do {
        try {
            request = drive
                    .files()
                    .list()
                    .setMaxResults(200)
                    .setQ("'root' in parents and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed=false");
            FileList files = request.execute();

            result.addAll(files.getItems());
            request.setPageToken(files.getNextPageToken());
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            ok = false;
        }
    } while (ok && request.getPageToken() != null && request.getPageToken().length() > 0);

    return result;
}
```